# How do I split the value returned by created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split

I am trying to split the value returned by the `created_at` method.

I am taking an object (`item`) and getting the time it was created at. I don't want the whole result and I am only interested in the day, month and year. How can I get this to work?

```
<% @items_in_basket.each do |item| %>
<% splliter = item.created_at.split(" ") %> 
<% time = @splliter[0] %>
```

I get this as a result:

```
undefined method 'split' for Wed, 31 Jul 2013 16:44:37 UTC +00:00:Time
```

Comment: maybe using item.created_at.to_s.split

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`created_at` returns an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` which you can simply call `day`, `month`, or `year` on to get those parts of the date. Example:

```
<% @items_in_basket.each do |item| %>
  Day: <%= item.created_at.day %>
  Month: <%= item.created_at.month %>
  Year: <%= item.created_at.year %>
<% end %>
```

This approach will be much more reliable than parsing the string format returned by `to_s`.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the date to string first before using the string method `split` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split).

```
<% splliter = item.created_at.to_s.split(" ") %>
```

The reason you are getting that error is because `Time` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html) class does not have `split` method.